# How can I undefine a Macro in the application code without modifying the header file?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have 2 things:
A library file and headers for the same.
I cannot access the source file. Only thing I can do is use the compiled library for my application. For this I specify the header files in a main.c file.
Lets say the code in header (application.h) specified a macro TEST as below:

**application.h**

```
#define TEST
```

In **application.c** file where I am including **application.h** header I have:

```
#ifdef TEST
{
do this
}
#else
{
do something else
}
```

Now in my main.c file I include the header application.h
I do not intend to use the macro TEST, meaning I want to undefine it.
Obviously I can undefine in the application.h file. But I don't want to do that. Is there a way to undefine the macro in main.c
Something like this:

**main.c**

```
#include"application.h"
#undef TEST
```

I tried this, when I run the program it doesn't work. 
Is there a way achieve this without modifying the application.h file?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Using `#undef` *is* the way to undefine a macro. Are you including other header files after your `#undef` that in turn might include `"application.h"`?

Comment: define it, or don't define it, in your makefile / project file

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE]. What you show here looks correct.

Comment: Are you including `application.h` in `application.c`? This is not clear in your question.

Comment: @abhinandanbr test your macro against the value not only the existence as in my answer and you will have the full controll

Comment: @MichaelWalz thanks for the edit suggestion. Clarified now.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are right. I am other header where its recalled again. Thanks a lot for that.

Comment: @abhinandanbr pretty unclear. In `main.c`, below the line `#undef TEST`, `TEST` is no more defined, unless you include `application.h` or some other file which defines it again below the line `#undef TEST`. Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: You can undefine the macro, but that won't change anything that has been conditional based on it before that point. It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Since you can modify the code where you want to undefine the macro you could just as easily not use it at all.

Comment: @MichaelWalz yes you are right. Sorry for that. I included other headers which redefine the application.h.

Comment: Sounds seeing a problem where there is none at all: "I do not intend to use the macro TEST" - So just don't use it. `#undef`ing a macro defined in an included file is normally bad coding style and renders your code hard, if not unmaintainable. Write readable and maintainable code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want to modify `main.c` without touching `application.c` or `application.h`.

If `application.c` is including `application.h`, then, as far as I know, you wont be able to undef anything. `application.c` and `main.c` are different compilation units, and defines are calculated, by the preprocessor, on compilation unit level.

If there is an unconditional `define` in `application.h`, then you will have to live with it.

Comment: Thanks for that. But since I am accessing the Macro in main.c, shouldn't I be able to undefine it? I am not clear.

Comment: If you undef in `main.c`, then it is undef'ed in `main.c`. It doesn't affect `application.c` at all. If you want to have it removed in `main.c`, then your solution should work. Treat different *.c files totally separately. They are compiled individually.